# PHP Traits Class Property Returns Null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

I am aiming to fetch values from database and assign it into a property in a trait. I know constructors are bad practice in traits but I'll just use it as a sample. I am using Laravel 8 and here's what I've done.

```
use App\User;
trait TestTrait {
   private $user;
   public function __construct() {
       $this->user = User::all();
   }
   public function test() {
       var_dump($this->user);
   }
}
```

What would be the better approach to achieve my goal on doing this? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First private $user should be public $user.
Because if you use private only the current class will have access to the field or
method.

Also in construct this part `$this->user = User:all();` not a good idea. You should
only pass the model in construct so then you have access to all of that model's
methods also inject the model. Change it like this:

```
 public function __construct(User $user) {
      $this->user = $user;
  }
   //and you can use it like this then
   public function test() {
       var_dump($this->user->all());
      /**or $this->user->find($id) and any methods that exists on that User class*/
   }
```